# Centralizar texto de acordo com o length

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou tendo dificuldade de montar uma lógica, onde vai escrever o nome do usuário em um certificado.

Afim de deixar sempre centralizado de acordo com o `length` do nome, eu tenho que ficar ajustando à `margem-left`, porém é permitido de 1 à 50, pra deixar sempre dinâmico, teria que fazer 50 `If` ou 50 `case`.

Nessa contagem do `length`, eu considero os espaços entre os nomes.

O tamanho da folha é A4 (*2480 px de largura 3508 px de altura*)

A idéia é centralizar o texto de acordo que diminuir/aumentar o tamanho do nome, baseando na posição da palavra **Parabéns**
Exemplo de nome que tem entre 0 a 10 de `length`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo de nome que tem entre 50+ de `length`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue código.

```
function certificado(codigo) {
                $.post("/MeusDados/ConsultarCertificados", { 'certificado': codigo }, function (data) {
                    if (data != null || data.length > 0) {
                        var nome = $("#nome").text();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var html = "";
                            html += "<div id=\"printDiv" + data[i].bPlanoCodigo + "\" class=\"col-sm-10\" style=\"width: 26%;\">";
                            html += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"JavaScript:printPartOfPage('printDiv" + data[i].bPlanoCodigo + "')\">";
                            if (nome.length >= 50) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 30%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length >= 45 && nome.length <= 50) {
                               html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 30%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length >= 40 && nome.length < 45) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 32%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length >= 35 && nome.length < 40) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 34%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length >= 30 && nome.length < 35) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 38%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length >= 25 && nome.length < 30) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 42%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }
                            else if (nome.length < 25) {
                                html += "<span  style=\"position: absolute; display:none; margin-left: 48%; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</span>"; 
                            }  
                            html += "<img class=\"imgCertificados\" src=\"data:image/png;base64," + data[i].bPlanoCertificado + "\"/>";
                            html += "</a>";
                            html += "</div>";
                            $("#certificado").append(html);
                        }
                        off();
                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você está tornando as coisas meio difíceis quando você poderia simplesmente inserir o texto em um elemento com largura de 100% e usar `text-align: center;` para deixar o texto sempre centralizado, independentemente do tamanho do texto.

Sugiro retirar todos esses `if`s e deixar apenas uma linha, trocar o `span` pelo `div`, remover o `margin-left` e adicionar `text-align: center` e `width: 100%`:

```
function certificado(codigo) {
 $.post("/MeusDados/ConsultarCertificados", { 'certificado': codigo }, function (data) {
     if (data != null || data.length > 0) {
         var nome = $("#nome").text();
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             var html = "";
             html += "<div id=\"printDiv" + data[i].bPlanoCodigo + "\" class=\"col-sm-10\" style=\"width: 26%;\">";
             html += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"JavaScript:printPartOfPage('printDiv" + data[i].bPlanoCodigo + "')\">";

             html += "<div style=\"text-align: center; width: 100%; position: absolute; display:none; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 37%; font-family: Trebuchet MS;\"\">" + nome + "\</div>"; 

             html += "<img class=\"imgCertificados\" src=\"data:image/png;base64," + data[i].bPlanoCertificado + "\"/>";
             html += "</a>";
             html += "</div>";
             $("#certificado").append(html);
         }
         off();
     }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pega a largura total da certificado subtrai a largura do texto, e divide o resultado da subtração igualmente em cada `margin` do texto.